ChromaDB error when deployed in an OpenShift Container
I have deployed **chromadb **in a openshift container. It was showing error with sqlite3. So I resolved it by Changing the __init__.py file. I added these lines
__import__('pysqlite3')
import pysqlite3
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules["pysqlite3"]

But now I am getting another error:
module 'chromadb' has no attribute 'config'
After exploring comments in this post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/78166411/25095147 by Abbas, I realized that the kernal need to be restarted. I am a newbie to OpenShift. So, I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me on how to resolve this?
I tried editting the configuration again and trying to restart the pod but both didnt work
